# Demystifying jamming in many-body systems

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, amorphous-solids

From a theoretical point of view, what has been the most successful approach to understanding jamming phenomena?

I understand there's still a lot of debate around this subject, namely whether a glass transition is really a phase transition, is jamming just a kinetic arrest of the system or is there anything fundamentally different between a jammed state and an amorphous solid, or even, is there a unified understanding of jammed states among different systems (polymers, granular, colloidal,...).

So in this view, this question is just to find out if in the recent years any game-changing understanding of jamming has arisen.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352339/fractal-structure-in-colloidal-systems ?

Comment: I believe there is an estabilished consensus that jamming is a complicated mess, while gravitational waves are more simple and fashionable, so very few good physicists are working on your unified, game changing theory...