# Fractal patterns on water

Tags: everyday-life, material-science, home-experiment, fractals

I stored water in a bucket (of aluminium probably), and some random fractal-like patterns are formed on the water:

[image]

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XT5W.jpg) for some more pictures.

Why did this happen?

I'm unable to reproduce it. How can I reproduce it again? Just leaving it alone openly doesn't work.

Comment: I have seen a similar film on the surface of water left in an opened tin can, also on a cup of tea, but not with such a pattern. This might be more a question of chemistry rather than physics.

Comment: According to [Scum on the Tea](http://www.teasmade.info/scum-on-the-tea/#more-1995) the film could be calcium carbonate (chalk) which comes out of solution in still water. Why the patterns form might also be due to chemistry.

Comment: @sammygerbil Posted https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81409/

Comment: Just for curiosity: If it's calcium carbonate, there's also a plethora of biological sources, as discussed in this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4718973/

Answer (score 17):

It looks a lot like the result of [diffusion-limited aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation) or more specifically [diffusion limited cluster aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_aggregation#Later_stages):

[image]

[Image source.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ParticleAggregationDLCAvsRLCA1.png)

If that's indeed the process responsible for the patterns, the question is then which particles are these. Likely candidates include dust and residues from previous use of the pot (milk, rice, etc.).

**Edit**: sammy gerbil's comment (and Ivan Neretin on the cross-posted [Chemistry.SE question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81409/fractal-patterns-on-water)) suggest a chemical source for the particles: carbonates. The picture below ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lattice_work_of_calcite_rafts_on_slow_dripping_calthemite_straw_drop.jpg)) shows calcite particles aggregating into a lattice on the water surface of a stalactite drop.

Calcite precipitattion is well summarized in [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcite_rafts), which describes (see also [this thesis](http://scholarsmine.mst.edu/masters_theses/4857/)) how calcite growth is dominated by surface nucleation and coalescence and how (de)gassing of CO$_2$ from the water is a common process [well known](http://www.uh.edu/~jbutler/kunming/carbonates.html) to lead to calcium carbonate precipitation.

[image]

Comment: How van I reproduce the effect ? (Though storage of milk and rice of improbable and didn't happened})

Comment: If you leave the pot open for the same time it takes for the furniture in your place to acquire a visible layer of dust (about a week in mine) without cleaning, I'd expect it to happen again. (If you do the experiment, do report the results here!)

Comment: No way that can happen. There are several instances where I kept a pot open, for several weeks, and this is there first time Im seeing this.

Comment: There are too many variables (time of the year, open/closed window, etc.) that could influence dust settling and, of course, maybe the pattern is something else, not DLA. I wouldn't bet on bacteria, since they tend to form films (as far as I know), but maybe fungi could create those filaments (a quick search on that possibility didn't reveal anything, though).

Comment: @ExcelHand, maybe calcite precipitation (see my reviewed answer) is our best lead - and then it's really a question for the Chemistry.SE to find out how to reproduce the conditions that led to this happening in your bucket.